# Why subpackage has been imported implicitly in Python?

Tags: python, import

I've a python package named `a` with two files in it `__init__.py` and `b`.

```
a/
a/__init__.py
a/b.py
```

The content of files:

```
# a/__init__.py
from .b import *
```

and

```
# a/b.py
c = 1
```

When I import `a` in Python, why I can use `a.b` directly? I'm confused because I do not import `b` explicitly in `a/__init__.py`.

If I use a **empty** `a/__init__.py`, then there's no `b` in `a`'s namespace. So it seems `from .b import *` (or `from .b import c`) also import `b`, why?

I've check the Python document and several posts in SO, but didn't find related issues.

---

I want all things from `b` but not `b` itself in `a`, then I could modify `a/__init__.py` to

```
# a/__init__.py
from .b import *
del b
```

Is this good?

Comment: Well, the part "why does import...?" is obviously a duplicate. That's how import stuff works. The part "can I use del... ?" isn't a complete duplicate. The answer is "yes, you can, it's pretty valid, look at `<python-lib-dir>/types.py` and find there the line `del sys, _f,  _g, _C, _c,  # Not for export`

Comment: @user3159253 Thanks for the information. I think that post and your comment answer my question well.